# React Native Navigation installation issue with React Native v0.51

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am having problem with the installation of the React Native Navigation with React Native v0.51. I saw that there are changes made to the index.ios and index.android file in favor of only one index.js file. I have made changes accordingly in AppDelegate.m but it still does not work.

[AppDelegate.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mmWQ.png)

[App boot up stuck in 4/478](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHXiY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working fine with the same changes that you've made in your `AppDelegate.m` file like yours. But, I am still unable to get android running.

While changing my `AppDelegate.m` file, xcode was unable to find the `RCTBundleURLProvider.h` so I had to re-link `React` under `Product > Schema > Manage Schema`

For android: Adding the following method inside `MainApplication` class of `MainApplication.java` worked for me.

```
@Override
public String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
}
```